# How to take values from a file, apply an equation to those values, and write them to file in c

Tags: c

How do I take values from a file, apply an equation to those values, and write them to file in c?
It seems simple, what I've tried just writes the same number as many times as I have samples. I would like to write a file with the new values.

````
   printf("Enter the number of sample values in the file minus 1.\n");  //11025
   scanf("%d",&n);

   printf("using %d sample values.\n",n);

    //  fseek(filein, "%lg", SEEK_SET);
   for ( c = 0 ; c <= n ; c++ )//     // Convert a reading (which goes from 0 - 65536) to a value (-1 - 1):
                                      // float voltage = sensor * (1 / 65536.0);
   {
      fseek(filein, n, SEEK_SET);
      fscanf(filein, "%lg", var);

      sum = var * (maxy / 65536.0);
//todo?

//todo?
   fprintf(fileout,"%lg\n",sum);
   }
   getchar();
fclose(filein);
fclose(fileout);
   return 0;
}



return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Redirect `stdin` to the input file, redirect `stdout` to your output file. Then read from the file, apply the equation and write back to stdout (will write to your file)

Comment: The full source for this program can be found on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/243116/how-to-take-values-from-a-file-apply-an-equation-to-those-values-and-write-the). The question is close to being closed there.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the code posted at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/243116/how-to-take-values-from-a-file-apply-an-equation-to-those-values-and-write-the.).

The `fseek()` is part of the problem because it keeps resetting to the beginning of the file.

You could do this without the use of `fseek()`, the file will open to the beginning and you're reading binary data.

You should probably use `fgets()` rather than `fscanf()` to read each line separately and the convert the text using `sscanf()`.

The format you want in the `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` is just `%g` or `%G`, the `%l` is for `long` integers.

Since the code is already using `stdlib.h` use the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` rather than `0`, `1`, `SUCCESS` or `ERROR`. **Note** that in C programming `SUCCESS` should be `0` and `ERROR` should be `1`.

This program desperately needs functions, you are repeating code in too many places.

The `for` loop is a bug waiting to happen because it can attempt to read past the end of the file. A `while` loop that incorporates both the counting of lines and `while not end of file` would be much better.

Declare variables as needed.